# preg_match search pattern and insert

Tags: preg-match, php-5.6

Hi can any one help me I try to insert one image or text from one variable using preg_match
First I record the Variable in one file and I call:

```
 function bbanner_fetch($a) {
                 $bannerUrl = get_config('bbanner','bannerUrl');
```

Follow by:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch($url){
case "/";
if(preg_match("/^(\Social)/", strtolower($line)))
{
    echo 'SEE DETAILS FOUND';
    $a->page['htmlhead'] .= "$bannerUrl" . "\r\n";
break;

}
```

That is a test using the word Social is In the Url /
But I not find or insert nothing My idea is insert a text or image embed
after the code `"<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $("#id_username").focus();} );</script>"`
from the variable bannerUrl

Any one have please any idea how is solve?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show what text you are trying to match, and/or what you want to replace it with? It's hard to see what's going on. What is `$line`?

Comment: Hi sorry that of $line1 not need to be there. I want only to find where say <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $("#id_username").focus();} );</script>"   and add after the content of $bannerUrl with this code   $a->page['htmlhead'] .= "$bannerUrl" . "\r\n";